# Raspberry Pi GPIO doesn't Hold Its State

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, wifi

I have been working on WiFi controlled robot car using Raspberry Pi-3.
Here I am using TCP server to send commands to raspberry pi.I was trying to place LEDs, but when I send command from client the Leds are in On state only for 20-30 sec. Here is the Led Program code i was working on, please help

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
from time import sleep

GPIO.setwarnings(False)
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
GPIO.setup(07, GPIO.IN)
def default():
    GPIO.setup(07, GPIO.OUT)
    GPIO.output(07, GPIO.HIGH)

def fled():
    GPIO.setup(07, GPIO.IN)
    state = GPIO.input(07)
    if(state is True):
            GPIO.setup(07, GPIO.OUT)
            GPIO.output(07, GPIO.LOW)

    else:
            GPIO.setup(07, GPIO.OUT)
            GPIO.output(07, GPIO.HIGH)
```

Comment: Have you tried using a loop to send the commands again and again

Comment: i tried while(1) loop but, if it is turned off once it isn't turning on again

Comment: i am a beginner, and i don't have much knowledge........please help